# Remove Span Tag on adding a text

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, jquery-ui

On dropdown change event i am making a column mandatory. if you see the below pic[image] for the first time when TypeofRequest="508web" what format should be return as becomes mandatory. The below code works fine for the first time when i change the dropdown. Once i change the value and come back it is adding 2 stars to the nobr text (refer screen shot below). [image]

how can we over come this

Function for the same

```
function MandateColumn(ColNames, mandatory)
{for(var i=0;i<ColNames.length;i++)
    {       
    if(mandatory=="True"){ var controlvalidate= $("[id^='"+ColNames[i]+"']").prev('td').text();
       var spanTag ="<span class=\"ms-formvalidation\"> *</span>";
       var newHtml1 = controlvalidate;
           newHtml =newHtml1 + spanTag;               
           $("nobr").filter(function()
              {return $(this).text() === controlvalidate;}).html(newHtml);}else{ }}}
```

Calling the above function (

```
var BPHCMandateCols= ['FormatShouldReturnas'];
                      MandateColumn(BPHCMandateCols,"True")
```

Comment: Did you try removing the "*" from `var spanTag ="<span class=\"ms-formvalidation\"> *</span>";` ?

Comment: Yes,If i Remove the * for the first time it self it will not add it.

Comment: So why do you purposely add * ?,however ms-formvalidation itself renders the *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by removing the span tag.

```
$("[id^='"+ColNames[i]+"']").prev('td').find('.ms-formvalidation').remove();
function MandateColumn(ColNames, mandatory)
{   
    for(var i=0;i<ColNames.length;i++)
    {

    if(mandatory=="True")
    {   
     $("[id^='"+ColNames[i]+"']").prev('td').find('.ms-formvalidation').remove();
       var controlvalidate= $("[id^='"+ColNames[i]+"']").prev('td').text();
       var newHtml1 = controlvalidate;
       $("nobr").filter(function()
              {return $(this).text() === controlvalidate;}).html(newHtml1);
       var spanTag ="<span class=\"ms-formvalidation\">*</span>";

           newHtml =newHtml1 + spanTag;               
           $("nobr").filter(function()
              {return $(this).text() === controlvalidate;}).html(newHtml);


    }
      else{ 


      }
    }
}
```